# docker reverse proxy DNS/networking issues

Tags: docker, networking, proxy, consul

I'll try to explain and draw this out

What I want to achieve:

[image: Diagram]

Sorry for the crappy paint diagram. Right now, it works perfectly if I hit it from the 10.10.10.0 network. The problem is DNS resolves jenkins.network.com to the 10.10.10.0 network. I want to go back through the proxy though as that has SSL termination to get to the sonarqube server. Is there a good way to accomplish this to keep the services behind the proxy? Do I need to create a second DNS server with the docker network on it? Is this possible to do with consul to have both the external and internal services point to the same domain name?

Edit:
Doing something like this would work, since everything goes through the proxies. So when jenkins hits sonar, it think's its ip really is 10.10.10.51 and it can hit it through there.
[image]

What I need it to do:
[image]
I need it to go out of the proxy, then come back in through the proxy. IE:

172.16.10.2 ---- 172.16.10.1 ----- 10.10.10.50 ----- Proxy then takes over to route to proper location (172.16.10.3:8080 or something)

Comment: So can you explain the problem with dig commands?

Comment: @TarunLalwani Let me try to expand on it. Basically it works as it should. I can hit the servers through the proxy. Problem is within the internal docker network. When resolving say sonarqube.mynetwork.com, it resolves to 10.10.10.50. Docker container uses the hosts DNS to get this. So jenkins gets the sonarqube address at 10.10.10.50, but because it's closed off to only the proxy at 172.16.10.1, it tries to hit the proxy at 10.10.10.50 and not the 172.16.10.1 address and you get no route found. Does that help?

Comment: So if i get the question correctly, you want on jenkin server `jenkins.network.com` to resolve to `172.16.10.1`? If yes then post your `docker-compose` file if using any

Comment: @tarun lalwani correct. So from the external network it resolves to the 10 address and internally resolves to the 172 address. I can't get to the file right now, but hopefully I'll get a chance soon and I'll ping you again. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you didn't post your compose. I am making few assumptions. The compose assumed is below

```
version: '3'

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    depends_on:
      - jenkins
      - sonar
  jenkins:
    image: jenkins
  sonar:
    image: sonarqube
```

And all of these run on `10.10.10.50`. Now if you set the DNS to `10.10.10.20` inside and outside, both `jenkins.network.com` will resolve to `10.10.10.50`. But inside the docker network you want `jenkins.network.com` to resolved to the IP of the container.

So if all above is correct then below is the simplest solution

```
version: '3'

service:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    depends_on:
      - jenkins
      - sonar
  jenkins:
    image: jenkins
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - jenkins.network.com
  sonar:
    image: sonar
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - sonar.network.com
```

On the nginx image i can reach `jenkins.network.com`

```
root@be6492f18851:/# telnet jenkins.network.com 8080
Trying 172.23.0.3...
Connected to jenkins.network.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

And you can do that from both jenkins and sonar containers and get the same results

**Edit-1**

If you want the DNS to go through proxy, you can change the aliases to that network

```
version: '3'

service:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    depends_on:
      - jenkins
      - sonar
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - sonar.network.com
          - jenkins.network.com
  jenkins:
    image: jenkins
  sonar:
    image: sonar
```

Comment: Yeah. Sorry. I haven't forgot, just got busy this weekend. I was thinking of something like that, but the issue would be I still need it to go through the proxy. One reason would be so termination. The other  would be to set up the correct port. Is this possible? I've been looking in docker swarm and service discovery, but haven't determined if that would solve my issue

Comment: @Matt, see the edits. It just a matter of updating the aliases to the proxy

Comment: Thats kind of what I was thinking I would have to do. I'll give it a shot and see if it will work for my use and let you know. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

how about use nginx to do reverse proxy?
if i didn't misunderstand, you want to listen 443 port
and  reverse to 172.16.10.1
below is an nginx config example

```
server {
listen 443;
root /data/up1; 

location / {
  proxy_pass       172.16.10.1;
  proxy_set_header Host      $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}
```

hope it helps

Comment: this nginx config should put at /etc/nginx/site-enable diretory

Comment: this is what I am currently doing, only thing is, when communicating from service to service, it doesn't have a route to get to the proxy internally. So yes, reverse proxy works, but because DNS resolves to the external network address, it can't get back in. Please see my comment above for further explanation. Thanks again.