# Docker container cannot access another container via VIRTUAL_HOST environment variable

Tags: docker, docker-compose

### I am new to docker, so I'm not really sure if I am correct on everything, but I will try my best to describe my situation.

I have two separate docker containers, one for the API and one for the frontend project. I used `jwilder/nginx-proxy` so I can access them both using hostnames(`VIRTUAL_HOST` environment variable on docker-compose). I can open my frontend project on the browser, and I can access my API using `postman`.

However, when I try to access my API endpoint using a httpclient on my frontend site, it returns:

`cURL error 6: Could not resolve host`

### What I've tried:

1. Connect the containers using `networks`. I can confirm that it works, because when I `ping` the container name, it returns a response.
2. Add `extra_hosts` to `docker-compose` on the frontend project. When I `curl` the hosts I added using the container `bash`, I get a response from the API.

Still, when I try to open the site, the error still persist. What am I missing?

Here is my `docker-compose` for my projects

Frontend:

```
version: "2"

services:      
  pixel_nginx:
    build: docker/nginx
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - nginx
    depends_on:
      - pixel_phpfpm
    volumes:
      - ./docker/nginx/symfony.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./:/www/
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=pixel-project.local
    extra_hosts:
      - "auth-xx-dev.pixel.local:172.18.0.7"
      - "listing-xx-dev.pixel.local:172.18.0.7"

  pixel_phpfpm:
    build: docker/phpfpm
    volumes:
      - ~/.ssh/known_hosts:/root/.ssh/known_hosts
      - ~/.ssh/id_rsa:/root/.ssh/id_rsa
      - ./:/www/
      - ./data/pixel-project/tmp/:/tmp/
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - php
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    environment:
      - ENV=development

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: pixelstack_pixel
```

Backend:

```
version: "2"

volumes:
  # this is the mysql data volume we are going to host the data inside
  dev_mysql_data:

services:
  # database container for local development purposes
  dev_database:
    image: mysql:5.6
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - database
    ports:
      - 3400:3306
    volumes:
      # mount the mysql_data docker volume to host the local development database
      - dev_mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
      # the provision file helps when trying to use the provision script to clone databases
      - ./provision.cnf:/provision.cnf
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pixel

  # This is the local development version of the nginx container
  dev_nginx:
    image: api-nginx:latest
    build: ./nginx
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - nginx
    depends_on:
      - dev_phpfpm
    volumes_from:
      - dev_phpfpm
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=~^(api|location|feedback|user|phone|loancalculator|seo|media|listing|development|kpi|newsletter|auth|worker|search)-xx-dev.pixel.local

  # This is the local development version of the phpfpm container
  dev_phpfpm:
    image: api-phpfpm:latest
    build:
      context: ./
      args:
        # this build might fail, if so, run in a terminal: export SSH_KEY=$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa)
        - SSH_KEY=$SSH_KEY
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - phpfpm
    depends_on:
      - dev_database
    volumes:
      # we override the images /www directory with the code from the live machine
      - ./:/www
    env_file:
      # inside this file, are the shared database secrets such as username/password
      - ./env/common
      - ./env/dev

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: pixelstack_pixel
```

Edit:
I'm using Ubuntu, and I set the hostnames on /etc/hosts

### Update:

When using `staging` domain hosted on `AWS`, the frontend project got response data as intended. So I can say that there is no problem on that side.

Comment: Have you the hostnames for both the frontend and api in your `/etc/hosts` file (assuming you're on 'nix)? Or is your dns service setup to resolve those `.local` addresses?

Comment: Yes, I have them at my `/etc/hosts` so I am able to access them on the browser and `postman`. I'm on `Ubuntu` by the way.

Comment: `However, when I try to access my API endpoint using a httpclient on my frontend site, it returns:` You mean you're exec'ing into the frontend container and running `curl` right?

Comment: No, I meant using a `httpclient` (like `axios`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### This works on my scenario, but I hope there will be a better solution:

I set the network aliases of the backend to the domains I need to use so that it goes through the proxy:

```
networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - auth-xx-dev.pixel.local
          - listing-xx-dev.pixel.local
```

Reference: [docker reverse proxy DNS/networking issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46002372/docker-reverse-proxy-dns-networking-issues)

Answer (score 1):

Both your nginx containers have the network alias `nginx` on the same network, meaning requests to `nginx` will get round robin'd between both (AFAIK, either way not good).

You probably want something like this for the frontend:

```
networks:
  default:
    aliases:
      - frontend-nginx
```

And something like this for backend

```
networks:
  default:
    aliases:
      - backend-nginx
```

Then from the frontend container just curl to `backend-nginx` and it should reach the backend container.

Tldr: you have duplicate aliases and those `.local` domains also can't be resolved within the containers.

Comment: I tried this, it works when I `curl` inside the container. But what I need is to make an API call from the frontend using the `.local` domains, which at the moment still not working.

Comment: No, it returns a response like what I'm receiving on `postman`

Comment: If it's `Could not resolve host` then it's most likely a problem with hosts or dns on the host machine. Or a typo :p.

Comment: If the frontend project works properly when an external API(hosted on the internet) is used, what can be the problem on my end?

Comment: What's the exact backend domain you try and reach?

Comment: Yeah, but which local one?

Comment: `auth-xx-dev.pixel.local`

Answer (score 0):

You should link them , add link in your docker-compose for nginx container then they can see each other . if you check /etc/hosts inside nginx contaner there will be name of database container and its ip address.

check this out : 
https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#update-containers

Comment: Thanks, but isn't this a legacy feature? I already setup the `network` for the docker containers.

Comment: Just stop them add link to your docker-compose.yaml , start them once again. it does not change anything except adding hostname and ip address of one in the other one.